# Why is my app leaking memory on screen rotation?

Tags: android, memory-leaks, bitmap, rotation

I have searched for hours on the subject of memory leaks and I cant seem to solve my problem. After exactly 9 rotations my app crashes with an OutOfMemory error. I have both Bitmaps and Drawables with Bitmaps in my app. I have tried putting in code that removes callbacks to drawables, I have tried setting all Bitmaps to null as well as manually calling the garbage collector. I had all of this code in the onSaveInstanceState() method since I assume that is called whenever the screen changes and before destruction of the view. None of these solutions worked.

I got some results with the Bitmaps turned to null, however that only added about another 9 screen rotations before another memory leak. Where is my leak? What am I doing wrong? I was under the impression that when a screen is rotated, everything is destroyed and recreated, that must obviously be false.

I dont want to post my code because A. there is a lot of it and B. its close to finishing and so becomes a company secret per se. If there is something you must absolutely see to solve this then I will post it. I think I just need a really good explanation of what is actually going on when the screen is rotated and how to correctly handle bitmaps and drawables. Note: This error does not pop up if I leave the app and then go back in, it only happens when the view is resized upon screen rotation.

I have about 7 bitmaps and 7 drawables, all created at launch and resized when the screen rotates. DOing that several times stops the app.

Some simplified code:
How I set up a Bitmap to a drawable. This one sets to a ClipDrawable as well:

```
//Full Bar
        colorbarMap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, R.drawable.colorbar);
        colorbarDraw = new BitmapDrawable(res, colorbarMap);
        colorbarDraw.setBounds(barX, barY, barX2, barY2);
        colorbarClip = new ClipDrawable(colorbarDraw, Gravity.BOTTOM, ClipDrawable.VERTICAL);
        colorbarClip.setBounds(barX, barY, barX2, barY2);
        colorbarClip.setLevel(currentLevel);

        //Empty Bar
        colorbaremptyMap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, R.drawable.colorempty);
        colorbaremptyDraw = new BitmapDrawable(res, colorbaremptyMap);
        colorbaremptyDraw.setBounds(barX, barY, barX2, barY2);
```

The above code runs once at the start of the view initializing based on this code:

```
private void init(){
        //System
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
            setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
        }
        res = getResources();
        options = new BitmapFactory.Options();

        viewTreeObserver = getViewTreeObserver();
        if (viewTreeObserver.isAlive()) {
            viewTreeObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
                @Override
                public void onGlobalLayout() {
                    getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
                    view_width = getWidth();
                    view_height = getHeight();
                    afterLayout();
                }
            });
        }
}
```

The first code snippet runs under the method: afterLayout()

Nothing is done with the bitmaps after this. Each bitmap is initialized with an x and y location based on the view width and height. That location is edited using a rectangle to set its bounds for example a moving object.

Comment: can you please show your code ? I mean a simplified version of what you are doing. BitMap are to be handled with care, and without further details it will be difficult to help you

Comment: do you need a high resolution bitmap or is the bitmap you are displaying is  small enough

Comment: Try using development tools, like [LeakCanary](https://github.com/square/leakcanary), to isolate the source of your difficulty. We cannot help you with a totally abstract question like this, particularly without a [mcve].

Comment: have you tried my answer @Travis Dewitt

Comment: The bitmaps are tiny and without much detail so Im scaling up a bit for certain screens but in all honesty they don't need to be very high res. Either way, the bitmaps render just fine. The problem happens when the screen rotates enough times. Something isnt being deleted and cleaned up.

Comment: Is the force stop because of out of memory error

Comment: Yes, the OOM. I solved my problem. I added in bitmap.recycle() lines for every bitmap, including the ones in the drawables. I then set all the bitmaps and drawables to null. I put this in the saveState method, and now I can rotate my screen all the time! I think these hoops I have to jump through to program in android safely are really pretty dumb though.

Answer (score 0):

If the Bitmap that to be displayed is small enough than use this or you don't need a high res image

```
  bitmapOption = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        bitmapOption.inScaled = true;
        bitmapOption.inSampleSize = 2;
  imageBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.getAbsolutePath(), bitmapOption);
```

this will reduce the amount of size of bitmap see the bald guys explanation

[optimizing bitmap](https://youtu.be/HY9aaXHx8yA?list=PLWz5rJ2EKKc9CBxr3BVjPTPoDPLdPIFCE)

put your bitmap loading code in try finally block and use this at the end

```
try {
      ...
 }finally {
      if (imageBitmap != null) {
                //recycle the bitmap to improve performance and avoid OO Exception
                imageBitmap.recycle();
                imageBitmap = null;
       }
  }
```

This will recycler the bitmap space taken by the image whenever GC is called

Comment: What would I be putting in to the try section and why am I putting the code in this particular block anyway? Is this going to be run at pause or onResume or on initialization? Also, this doesnt solve my problem, it simply pushes it further back. My problem happens when the images are resized tons and tons of times, then the app crashes, meaning somewhere for some reason, something isnt being let go.